# I want to add an button onclick function, to add several toasts in javascript

Tags: javascript, toast, buttonclick

I have a form. And I want to write an onClick function which whenever is clicked, a toast including inputs value appears at the end of the page.
here I wrote a function that produce a toast just on the first click.

```js
function Function1() {
  var y = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
  var z = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var x = document.getElementById("toast1");

  x.innerHTML = y + " has a " + z + "<span >&times;</span>";
  x.className = "show";
}
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <h5>Select the owner?</h5>
  <div class="form-group col mx-auto" style="width: 80%;">
    <label for="validationDefault01" class="sr-only">households</label>
    <select
      class="custom-select place-holder form-control form-control-lg OwnerName"
      style="font-size: 15px;"
      id="validationDefault01"
      style="border-radius: 2px;"
      required
    >
      <option value="" selected hidden>Choose...</option>
      <option value="Jack London"> Jack London</option>
      <option value="Sarah London"> Sarah London</option>
      <option value="Mike"> Mike</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br />
  <h5>What is the brand?</h5>
  <div class="input-group mx-auto" style="border-radius: 8px; width: 75%;">
    <label for="validationCustom01" class="sr-only">Brand</label>
    <input
      class="form-control brand"
      type="text"
      required
      id="validationCustom01"
      style="font-size: 15px; height: 40px;"
      placeholder="Brand"
    />
    <div class="valid-feedback">correct</div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <h5>What is the model year?</h5>
  <div class="input-group mx-auto" style="border-radius: 8px; width: 75%;">
    <label for="validationCustom01" class="sr-only">yyyy</label>
    <input
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
      required
      id="validationCustom01"
      style="font-size: 15px; height: 40px;"
      onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()"
      placeholder="yyyy"
    />
    <div class="valid-feedback">correct</div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <h5 class="mx-2">How much is worth?</h5>
  <div class="input-group mx-auto" style="border-radius: 8px; width: 75%;">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div
        class="input-group-text font-weight-bold"
        style="
          font-size: 15px;
          background-color: rgba(50, 157, 105, 1);
          color: white;
        "
      >
        $
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="validationDefault01" class="sr-only">deposite</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control floatNumber"
      id="validationDefault01"
      style="font-size: 15px;"
      onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()"
      onkeyup="FormatCurrency(this)"
      placeholder="example: 10000"
      required
    />
  </div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button
        class="quebtn1 mx-auto"
        style="width: 130px;"
        type="button"
        onclick="Function1()"
      >
        Add Vehicle
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <button class="quebtn1 float-right" type="button">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <button class="quebtn1" type="submit">Next</button>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-0 mx-auto text-center">
      <div
        class="toast-body toast no-gutters"
        data-autohide="false"
        role="alert"
        aria-live="assertive"
        aria-atomic="true"
        id="toast1"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But I want when user fill the form and click on "add vehicle" button to add another vehicle again and again, each time a toast including information of the previous vehicle user added, produce.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a heads up: I edited your question to make the indentation and stuff nicer as well as getting rid of a few unnecessary closing tags. For the future, try to do this yourself when posting a question, because it makes it a whole lot easier for us to help you :) There are tools like https://prettier.io/ that will do this for you and are great to install the corresponding plugin to your text editor.

Comment: hey Adam thx a lot for your your attention and notice you have mentioned. I will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why you aren't getting the results you're looking for, you have to understand the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). Currently, whenever the button is clicked, you are always changing the same DOM element.

```
var x = document.getElementById("toast1");

x.innerHTML = y + " has a " + z + "<span >&times;</span>";
x.className = "show";
```

See how you're selecting the element with the ID of `toast1` and manipulating that element every time by setting its `innerHTML` and `className`?

What you want to do is create a *new* element, and place that new element *underneath* the element with the ID of `toast1`.

To create an new element, you would use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```
var newEl = document.createElement("p");

newEl.innerHTML = y + " has a " + z + "<span >&times;</span>";
newEl.className = "show";
```

And then to insert it use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
x.appendChild(newEl);
```

Here's the complete code:

```js
function Function1() {
  var y = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
  var z = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var x = document.getElementById("toast1");
  var newEl = document.createElement("div");

  newEl.innerHTML = y + " has a " + z + "<span >&times;</span>";
  newEl.className = "show";
  x.appendChild(newEl);
}
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <h5>Select the owner?</h5>
  <div class="form-group col mx-auto" style="width: 80%;">
    <label for="validationDefault01" class="sr-only">households</label>
    <select
      class="custom-select place-holder form-control form-control-lg OwnerName"
      style="font-size: 15px;"
      id="validationDefault01"
      style="border-radius: 2px;"
      required
    >
      <option value="" selected hidden>Choose...</option>
      <option value="Jack London"> Jack London</option>
      <option value="Sarah London"> Sarah London</option>
      <option value="Mike"> Mike</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br />
  <h5>What is the brand?</h5>
  <div class="input-group mx-auto" style="border-radius: 8px; width: 75%;">
    <label for="validationCustom01" class="sr-only">Brand</label>
    <input
      class="form-control brand"
      type="text"
      required
      id="validationCustom01"
      style="font-size: 15px; height: 40px;"
      placeholder="Brand"
    />
    <div class="valid-feedback">correct</div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <h5>What is the model year?</h5>
  <div class="input-group mx-auto" style="border-radius: 8px; width: 75%;">
    <label for="validationCustom01" class="sr-only">yyyy</label>
    <input
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
      required
      id="validationCustom01"
      style="font-size: 15px; height: 40px;"
      onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()"
      placeholder="yyyy"
    />
    <div class="valid-feedback">correct</div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <h5 class="mx-2">How much is worth?</h5>
  <div class="input-group mx-auto" style="border-radius: 8px; width: 75%;">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div
        class="input-group-text font-weight-bold"
        style="
          font-size: 15px;
          background-color: rgba(50, 157, 105, 1);
          color: white;
        "
      >
        $
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="validationDefault01" class="sr-only">deposite</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control floatNumber"
      id="validationDefault01"
      style="font-size: 15px;"
      onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()"
      onkeyup="FormatCurrency(this)"
      placeholder="example: 10000"
      required
    />
  </div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button
        class="quebtn1 mx-auto"
        style="width: 130px;"
        type="button"
        onclick="Function1()"
      >
        Add Vehicle
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <button class="quebtn1 float-right" type="button">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <button class="quebtn1" type="submit">Next</button>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-0 mx-auto text-center">
      <div
        class="toast-body toast no-gutters"
        data-autohide="false"
        role="alert"
        aria-live="assertive"
        aria-atomic="true"
        id="toast1"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Also, here are some tips that aren't directly related to your question:

- There's also [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of stuff like `getElementsByTagName`. It lets you basically use CSS selectors to select elements, which a lot of people find easy to use.
- For this sort of DOM manipulation, you also might want to try using the jQuery library
- It's good to learn how DOM manipulation works for educational purposes, but on real projects the field has moved towards UI libraries like React and Vue.
- You named your function `Function1`. This works, but it's better if you could name it something more descriptive, like `addVehicle`. That way it's more clear what it's doing. With one function `Function1` is probably fine, but imagine if you had 12 functions and had to think to yourself, "Wait, what is `Function3` doing again? Did I want to use `Function7`?"
- It's good to learn by doing, but it's also good to mix that with a more "bottom up" approach of reading books and stuff to give you the foundation you'll need for fun projects like this.

Comment: Vowwww. Thank you very very much. I am surprised getting Such a great answer and teaching. And thx for those great tips you gave me.Sorry for my basic questions. I am trying to develop my knowledge and I will start reading books.

Comment: Sure thing! I remember what it was like when I was getting started so I try to pay it forward :)